# How can one Python module break another?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

After several hours of debugging and trial and error, I found that importing two independent Python modules caused a function in one of them to stop working.

```
import arcpy
# works
sde_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"C:\temp\test.sde")
```

Yet:

```
import arcpy
import rtree
# fails
sde_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"C:\temp\test.sde")
```

The two Python modules are [rtree](https://github.com/Toblerity/rtree) and ESRI's [arcpy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000v00000001000000), both of which I have running on Windows (the issue occurs on both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2, and on 32 bit and 64 bit Python installations).

I [logged the issue](http://github.com/Toblerity/rtree/issues/10), but I'd like to know what are the possible causes of one module breaking a function in another?

I had a quick check for globals, and modifying the system path. Both also rely on DLLs.

What other factors could be responsible?

Comment: It happens when you do `from rtree import *`, and `from arcpy import *` and there are conflicting function names

Comment: Python being a dynamic language there are a multitude of ways a module could behave badly and break other stuff. Monkey patching built-ins or standard modules are good candidates for mucking up other modules.

Answer (score 2):

It happens when using:

```
from (module) import *
```

if both modules have functions with the same names.
Shamelessly taken from @karthikr

Comment: It is definitely the first thing to check, but in this case I have two simple imports